# Redis hash structure does not make memory efficient as described

Tags: memory, hash, redis

my redis version is redis-version 3.2.9 and I Modify redis.conf,
`hash-max-ziplist-entries 256`
`hash-max-ziplist-value 4096`

however, the results do not play As descriped in Memory Optimization(redis hash structure can make memory more-efficient),

as well, Capacity assessment also confuse me, I will show the result I get below

[image]
[image]

As showed above, redis string key-value: the first pic shows that 3085 and 4086 uses the same memory. The second pic shows that 4096 uses more memory(about 1024 byte per key), not 4096 per key. jemalooc

I hope someone can help me, thank you

Comment: Hey! can you reframe your question. Not able to understand what you are asking

Comment: what I mean is : 1、redis hash structure do not make memory efficient while it uses ziplist; 2、redis memory assessment do not work as jemalloc does

Comment: what is 3085, 4096?? number of entries in ziplist?

Comment: ok, let me describe again, as showed below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlOnz.png
mem_fragmentation_ratio is 0.84
I do not why

Comment: i hope you got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Redis internally, for optimisation purpose, stores entries in a data-structure called **ZipList** which directly works with memory addresses.
So the optimisation is actually compaction and reduction of memory wastage in using and maintaining pointers.

```
ziplist:

+----+----+----+
|  a |  b | c  |
+----+----+----+
```

now, let's say we did an update in value for `b` and the value size has increased from let's say 10 to 20 bytes.
We have no way to fit that value in between. So we do a zip-list resizing.

```
ziplist:

+----+--------+----+
|  a |   bb   | c  |  
+----+--------+----+
```

So, when when doing resizing, it will create a new block of memory with the larger size and copy the old data to that newly allocated memory and then it will deallocate the old memory area.
Since memory is moved in such cases it leads to memory fragmentation.

Redis also does memory de-fragmentation which can bring this ratio down to less than 1.
This fragmentation is calculated as,

```
(resident memory) / (memory allocation)
```

**How is resident memory less than allocated memory you ask!**
Normally the allocated memory should be fully contained in the resident memory, nevertheless there are a few exceptions:

- If parts of the virtual memory are paged out to disk, the resident memory can be smaller than the allocated memory.
- There are cases of shared memory where the shared memory is marked as used, but not as resident.

Comment: I do not understand "shared memory is marked as used, but not as resident", can you describe it in detail

Comment: So, generally when a memory is reserved for a process it is not actually mapped to a physically memory by the kernel. By this I mean, the kernel delays the memory mapping until the process actually does some operation on the memory space.